# How to pass arguments when creating kubeflow pipeline yaml file?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, minikube, kubeflow

### Environment

- minikube  latest (kubernets 1.21.14)
- kustomize 3.2.0
- kubectl 1.21.14
- kubeflow/manifests v1.6-branch
- KFP version 1.8.13

I want to create kubeflow pipelines file to run pipeline on GKE.
I created the pipeline according to
[Getting started building a pipeline](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/build-pipeline/#getting-started-building-a-pipeline).
**I cannot get kubeflow pipeline yaml file by following method.**

```
kfp.compiler.Compiler().compile(
    pipeline_func=my_pipeline,
    package_path='pipeline.yaml',
    pipeline_parameters={'url': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/ml-pipeline-playground/iris-csv-files.tar.gz'})
```

I got `TypeError: compile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pipeline_parameters'`
From [this implementation](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/3b1bd08ce0188605cff90e3f14563d55436aac96/sdk/python/kfp/compiler/compiler.py#L62), I should be able to use `pipeline_parameters` argument for `kfp.compiler.Compiler().compile`.

### Reference

- [Getting started building a pipeline](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/build-pipeline/#getting-started-building-a-pipeline)
- [kfp.compiler package](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/kfp.compiler.html#module-kfp.compiler)
- [Option 1: Compile and then upload in UI](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/build-pipeline/#option-1-compile-and-then-upload-in-ui)

Comment: I also asked about it in github and got answer.I was mislead to old document. https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/8175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass default pipeline parameters for your pipeline. You can do it directly in the function definition of the pipeline like this:

```
@dsl.pipeline(name='name')
def my_pipeline(a=1, b='default value'):
  # pipeline code
  pass
```

For a minimal example of a full pipeline, you can take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@trannhatquang1104/minimal-kubeflow-pipeline-example-f13cd5dc84ac).
From my experience working with Kubeflow, a lot of the documentation are wrong or not up-to-date. Many times, you have to find a workaround.